# Structure for custom key bindings?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to create a structure for storing and dispatching custom (by the end user) key bindings.

I was thinking of a structure like:

```
UserPrefs:{
   KeyBindings:{
      "I":{
         Key:"I",
         CTRL:true,
         Action:"ToggleInteractiveMode"
      },
      "S":{
         Key:"S",
         CTRL:true,
         Action:"SaveSelectedRecord"
      },
      "E":{
         Key:"E",
         CTRL:true,
         Action:"EditSelectedRecord"
      },
   },
}
```

And then a global KeyUp function like:

```
eGlobalKeyUp = function(e, eventThis){

   if(!e.which in UserPrefs.KeyBindings)
      return; // This key or combo is not bound

   if(UserPrefs.KeyBindings[e.which].CTRL === e.ctrlKey &&
      UserPrefs.KeyBindings[e.which].ALT === e.altKey &&
      UserPrefs.KeyBindings[e.which].SHIFT === e.shiftKey     
   ){
      UserPrefs.KeyBindings[e.which].Action();
   }
}
```

Of course the problem with this model is, by using the Key as the *Key*, you can't store more than one combo for a given key, ie. you can't have a `CTRL+L` and a `CTRL+SHIFT+L`, which of course you would want. I do like the ability to use in vs a loop though.

Has anyone implemented a structure for user defined hot key mapping that they could share?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved such problem is this way:
First, describe all key combos:

```
var keyBindings = [
  {
    Key: "I",
    Action: "ToggleInteractiveMode"
  },
  {
    Key: "I",
    CTRL: true,
    Action: "ToggleInteractiveMode+Ctrl"
  },
  {
    Key: "I",
    CTRL: true,
    SHIFT: true,
    Action: "ToggleInteractiveMode+Ctrl+Shift"
  }
];
```

Then init keys:

```
keyBindings.forEach( function( keyObject ) {
  var keyName = "";
  if ( keyObject.CTRL ) {
    keyName += "CTRL_";
  }
  if ( keyObject.SHIFT ) {
    keyName += "SHIFT_";
  }
  keyName += keyObject.Key;
  keyBindings[keyName] = keyObject;
} );
```

Now keyBindings contains keys like "I","CTRL_I","CTRL_SHIFT_I".

Now in eGlobalKeyUp you can use something like this:

```
var prefix = "";
if ( e.ctrlKey ) {prefix += "CTRL_";}
if ( e.shiftKey ) {prefix += "SHIFT_";}

if ( keyBindings[prefix + e.which] ) {
  keyBindings[prefix + e.which].Action();
}
else {
  return;
}
```